# Postfix deny relay for some virtual users

Tags: mysql, postfix, dovecot, sasl, smtp-auth

I'm using Postfix as MTA and relay. Users that wish to send e-mail from a remote system authenticates and Postfix hands that to Dovecot, and this works well. But how can I limit which users can use SMTP+Authentication, without limiting access to POP or IMAP?

To me it doesn't matter if the block is in Dovecot's SASL authentication, or by Postfix looking it up in a table.

Using Postfix 2.9.6 for SMTP, Dovecot 2.0.19 for POP, IMAP and SASL. Virtual users are stored in MySQL 5.5.40.

```
root@mx1:~# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 51200000
mydestination = localhost, mx1.mydomain.tld
myhostname = virtmx.mydomain.tld
mynetworks = /etc/postfix/mynetworks
myorigin = /etc/mailname
policy-spf_time_limit = 3600s
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_relay_domains_maps.cf
setgid_group = vmail
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unauth_pipelining, check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rhsbl_reverse_client dbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/mydomain.tld-virtmx.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/mydomain.tld-virtmx.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_medium_cipherlist = AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_transports_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:88
virtual_mailbox_base = /srv/mailbox
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 999
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_uid_maps.cf
```

If it helps, these are the SQL queries used:

```
mysql_mynetworks.cf
query = SELECT address FROM mailnetworks WHERE address='%s' and active='Y'

mysql_relay_domains_maps.cf
query = SELECT domain FROM maildomains WHERE domain='%s' AND backupmx = 1 AND active = 1

mysql_sender_maps.cf
query = SELECT address FROM mailsender WHERE username='%s'

mysql_transports_maps.cf
query = SELECT transport FROM maildomains WHERE domain='%s' AND transport != '' AND active=1

mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
query = SELECT goto FROM mailaliases AS a LEFT JOIN maildomains AS dom ON dom.domain=a.domain WHERE address='%s' AND dom.active=1 and a.active=1

mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
query = SELECT domain FROM maildomains WHERE domain='%s' AND backupmx='0' AND active=1

mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
query = SELECT maildir FROM mailboxes AS box LEFT JOIN maildomains AS dom ON dom.domain=box.domain WHERE username='%s' AND dom.active=1 AND box.active=1

mysql_virtual_uid_maps.cf
query = SELECT uid FROM mailboxes AS box LEFT JOIN maildomains AS dom ON box.domain=dom.domain WHERE username='%s' AND box.active=1 and dom.active=1
```

Answer (score 6):

**This feature was available to postfix version 2.11**.

You can use `check_sasl_access` parameter to enforce restrictions based on SASL username. Of course you need to put it above `permit_sasl_authenticated`. Please refer to [man 5 postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_sasl_access) for complete documentation.

Example configuration, taken from [Postfix SASL Howto](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html)

```
# main.cf
smtpd_relay_restrictions = 
    ..., 
    check_sasl_access hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_blacklist,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    ...
```

and

```
# sasl_blacklist
# Use this when smtpd_sasl_local_domain is empty.
username   REJECT
# Use this when smtpd_sasl_local_domain=example.com.
username@example.com REJECT
```

Comment: Updated the post with my versions. Any idea how to work it out with Dovecot 2.0.19 and Postfix 2.9.6?

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the output of `postconf -n`?  Maybe we can find a workaround  with postfix smtpd_*_restrictions

Answer (score 3):

**Some workaround for postfix < 2.11**

[The author suggested](http://marc.info/?l=postfix-users&m=135837242522829&w=2) that you need combination of `reject_sender_login_mismatch` and `check_sender_access`.

- Parameter [reject_sender_login_mismatch](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch) will reject if the sender doesn't defined in their permitted username. Looks like you already have query for this in `mysql_sender_maps.cf`.
- Parameter `check_sender_access` will reject email based on sender.

So, you need something like

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_sender_maps.cf
smtpd_relay_restriction = ...
    ...
    reject_sender_login_mismatch
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_reject
    ...
```

and

```
#sasl_reject
username@example.com   REJECT
```

---

[The alternative](http://marc.info/?l=postfix-users&m=135837495924026&w=2) is using lightweight [postfwd](http://postfwd.org/) to perform some kind of restriction for SASL username. You can use `sasl_username` parameter to control this behavior. See this [documentation page of postfwd](http://postfwd.org/doc.html) for further information.